# Can't save tf.keras.Model with custom serving method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to save my trained tf.keras.Model:

```
class ServingModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.float32)])
    def serve(self, series):
        sample = tf.expand_dims(series, axis=0)
        predictions = self.model(sample)
        return {
            'target': predictions
        }

...
model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)
mod = ServingModule(model)
tf.saved_model.save(mod, export_dir=output_dir, signatures={"serving_default": mod.serve})
```

However, i get the following error:

`Attempted to save a function b'__inference_serve_8765' which references a symbolic Tensor Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool) that is not a simple constant. This is not supported.`

What Tensor is meant with `Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)` and how can i properly save my tf.keras.Model with a custom serving method?

Comment: Hi @Plus Ultra, Can you provide a minimum reproducible code so that it would be much easier to trace where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I was able recreate the error in Tensorflow version 1.15.2.

**Tensorflow 1.15.2:**

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,3), name='digits')
x = layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', name='GRU',dropout=0.1)(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='3_layer')

model.save('model',save_format='tf')
```

Output -

```
1.15.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d1631e6a8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d1631e6a8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d16240510> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d16240510> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d161601e0> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d161601e0> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d1622b598> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d1622b598> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d16199510> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d16199510> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15f21bf8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15f21bf8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15e8ed90> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15e8ed90> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15ea8ae8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15ea8ae8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15ebc8c8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15ebc8c8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d1600f7b8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d1600f7b8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15e50c80> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15e50c80> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function canonicalize_signatures.<locals>.signature_wrapper at 0x7f9d160c28c8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: Bad argument number for Name: 3, expecting 4
WARNING: Entity <function canonicalize_signatures.<locals>.signature_wrapper at 0x7f9d160c28c8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: Bad argument number for Name: 3, expecting 4
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15e6fae8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING: Entity <function Function._initialize_uninitialized_variables.<locals>.initialize_variables at 0x7f9d15e6fae8> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-22c5d8bef576> in <module>()
     12 model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='3_layer')
     13 
---> 14 model.save('model',save_format='tf')

5 frames
/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in map_resources(self)
    289                 ("Attempted to save a function {} which references a symbolic "
    290                  "Tensor {} that is not a simple constant. This is not "
--> 291                  "supported.").format(concrete_function.name, capture))
    292           copied_tensor = constant_op.constant(capture_constant_value)
    293           node_id = len(self.nodes)

ValueError: Attempted to save a function b'__inference_GRU_layer_call_fn_13135' which references a symbolic Tensor Tensor("dropout/mul_1:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32) that is not a simple constant. This is not supported.
```

This error has been fixed in the latest versoin of tensorflow 2.2.0.

**Tensorflow 2.2.0:**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,3), name='digits')
x = layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', name='GRU',dropout=0.1)(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='3_layer')

model.save('model',save_format='tf')

print("model saved")
```

Output -

```
2.2.0-rc4
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: model/assets
model saved
```

Comment: @Plus Ultra - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.